# SSL certificate error on wamp

Tags: php, apache, ssl

Trying to install the SSL certificate which I bought from Symantec. When using the `httpd -t` via `cmd` to see if the syntax was OK. It gives the following error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 72 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/ht
tpd-ssl.conf:
SSLSessionCache: 'c' session cache not supported (known names: shmcb,dbm,memcache,default). Maybe you need to load the appropriate socache module (mod_socache_c?).
```

I have uncommented the following lines to load the modules in `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

I have also double checked the modules directory to see if `mod_socache_shmcb.so` exists or not. It does!
Not sure what else I could try?

Comment: I think `.so` modules are compiled for the linux version. you need the `.dll` windows version of the module.

Comment: Apache use `.so` extension on Windows

Comment: @li-on oh ok thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if SSLSessionCache option is configured properly
eg.

`SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:C:\wamp\Apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"`

Comment: (hint: it's on line 72 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/extra/ht
tpd-ssl.conf . See also https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslsessioncache)

Comment: Perfect solution. I added the shmcb part before the address and it worked! thanks @li-on